# How to handle drag and drop in Cypress when any cypress method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, drag-and-drop, cypress

I've got a problem with drag and drop method in cypress I try to do it in three ways but none of them works. I attached my code which does not work, maybe do you have suggestion what could works in my case.
Of course manual drag and drop works fine

```js
  cy.get('gucci-draggable-item')
    .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
    .trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, pageX: 600, pageY: 300 })
    .trigger('mouseup', { which: 1 });
```

```js
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;
cy.get('gucci-draggable-item')
  .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });
cy.get('.expand-sheet-container')
  .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });
cy.get('gucci-draggable-item')
  .trigger('dragend');
```

and also using @4tw/cypress-drag-drop

```js
cy.get('gucci-draggable-item').drag('.expand-sheet-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am experiencing issues getting this to work correctly but, I notice the targeted element in your code does not have a class or id. It should be something like:

```
cy.get('#gucci-draggable-item')
```

Comment: That's not a problem gucci-draggable-item is not id, this is an element like span or div